# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment doesn't work in command line call

Tags: python, command-line, nltk, global

I am aware that there are many solutions to this kind of question. However, none of them seems to have helped with my case. This is the code I'm referring to:

```
from nltk.book import text4

def length_frequency(length):
    '''
    Parameter: length as an integer
    '''
    # finds words in given length
    counter = 0
    word_in_length = {}
    for word in text4:
        if len(word) == length and word not in word_in_length:
            word_in_length[word] = text4.count(word)
    for key in word_in_length:
        if word_in_length[key] > counter:
            max = word_in_length[key]
            counter = max
            max_word = key
    print(f'The most frequent word with {length} characters is "{max_word}".\nIt occurs {counter} times.')

length_frequency(7)

Output:
The most frequent word with 7 characters is "country".
It occurs 312 times.
```

When I try this code in PyCharm, it works without problems. However, if I use it via command line call it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program5.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "program5.py", line 60, in main
    length_frequency(input_length)
  File "program5.py", line 35, in length_frequency
    print(f'The most frequent word with {length} characters is "{max_word[0]}".\nIt occurs {counter} times.')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_word' referenced before assignment
```

Of course, for the command line call I import sys and use sys.argv as an argument for length. I have tried adding global max_word at the beginning of the function, but it does not work. I have not assigned any variable like max_word before this function.

Comment: If `word_in_length` is empty, `max_word` will never be assigned.  So the difference is that in the command line environment, `text4` is empty.

Comment: As there is an assignment to variable `max_word` anywhere in the function, and as it isn’t declared global, then by definition `max_word` is a local variable. And yes as @Samwise points out about that it is possible for it never being assigned a value, then you get the error.

Comment: @Samwise How come it is empty?

Comment: If the `if` is never true then `max_word` is never assigned a value.

Comment: I guess the other possibility is that your `length` parameter causes the relevant conditions to never match?

Comment: @Samwise It works just fine in Pycharm, I've tested it with every length from 1-10 and there are definitely matches. I do not really get why the text4 should suddenly be empty in the command line environment. If that's the case, how could that be solved?

Comment: I'll bet that you're somehow passing a string instead of an integer for the `length` parameter in the non-working scenario.  The length of any word in the text will *never* be equal to `"7"`, for example.

Comment: @jasonharper OP did mention using `sys.argv` to pass in value. I bet you are right. OP should share the exact code that fails.

Comment: @jasonharper That was it, it took the argument as a string instead of an integer. It works now, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some error checking to the function to help you debug:

```
def length_frequency(length: int) -> None:
    '''
    Parameter: length as an integer
    '''
    assert isinstance(length, int), f"{repr(length)} is not an int!"
    word_counts = {word: text4.count(word) for word in set(text4) if len(word) == length}
    assert word_counts, f"No words in corpus with length {length}!"
    max_word = max(word_counts.keys(), key=word_counts.get)
    print(f"The most frequent word with {length} characters is {max_word}")
```

(I simplified the implementation a bit just for my own benefit in making it easier to understand -- I'm pretty sure it does the same thing with less confusion.)

Note that adding type annotations also means that if you had a line of code like, say:

```
length_frequency(sys.argv[1])
```

if you were to run `mypy` it would tell you about the error, no `assert` required:

```
test.py:19: error: Argument 1 to "length_frequency" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```